# should you include DV in MCAR when missings are found in IVs?

Tags: mcar

can anyone please help me with this question, can't find a satisfactory answer on the stats sites.
A reviewer of one of my articles commented that I should include the DVs in my MCAR analysis. But i only have missings in my IVs. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is some guidance in this [article](http://www.bmj.com/content/338/bmj.b2393) by Sterne and colleagues in the BMJ. They point to a cautionary tale where not including the outcome in the imputation model was potentially mis-leading. So the reviewer has a point.